# How to make a button with square edges in material3?

Tags: android, xml

I styled the cornerSize property to 0dp, but my button still has rounded edges, how can I fix this? The style is connected to the button through themes and it registers for other changes. There are no interfering properties.

```
<!-- Button -->
    <style name="Theme.CowboysStore.Button" parent="Widget.Material3.Button.ElevatedButton">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="backgroundTint">@color/smalt</item>
        <item name="cornerSize">0dp</item>
    </style>
    <!--Button -->
```

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonSignIn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/normal_300"
            android:text="@string/sign_in_login"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textInputLayoutPassword"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>
```

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <style name="Base.V27.Theme" parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/white_50pc</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.CowboysStore" parent="Base.V27.Theme">
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/black_20pc</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/smalt</item>
        <item name="textInputStyle">@style/Theme.CowboysStore.TextInputLayout</item>
        <item name="materialButtonStyle">@style/Theme.CowboysStore.Button</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Added a screenshot, on the left is my button, on the right is the expected one
[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JS1Xr.png)

Comment: Where did you apply the style?

Comment: Added a code with a theme, it is specified in the manifest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace 'cornerSize' with 'cornerRadius'